# "process information unavailable", jps command in linux

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

we use jps command to see which hadoop process is live, but since few days jps command is showing output like this.

```
    [root@master ~]# jps
    3814 -- process information unavailable
    2266 -- process information unavailable
    6197 -- process information unavailable
    7092 Jps
    6415 -- process information unavailable
    6027 -- process information unavailable
```

the actual ouput should be

```
[root@slave ~]# jps
5039 Jps
2764 Application
2468 DataNode
2349 TaskTracker
```

is there any way which it will show me process information??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just remove `hsperfdata_` folder from your `/tmp` folder and run `jps` again.

Comment: will it harm any of the processes? What is the purpose of these hsperfdata_ folder?

Comment: It's a directory for storing performance data for Java processes.  Take a look at this [Java reference page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) and look under the `UsePerfData` heading.